# IPN URL for Magento Multi Store

Tags: multistore, paypal

You can set up PayPal IPN URLs but you can only add one, so what do I do if I have a multistore?? The problem at the moment is that a user clicks on CANCEL at the PayPal page and they are redirected back to the wrong website. I want users to stay on the same website, not get redirected to another website in my Magento installation.